# FileNotFoundException but the file exists

Tags: hadoop, distributed-caching, distributed-cache

I'm getting this exception in Hadoop while trying to read file that was added to distributed cache, and the strange thing is that the file exists on the given location

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist: /tmp/hadoop-pera/mapred/local/taskTracker/distcache/-1517670662102870873_-1918892372_1898431787/localhost/work/output/temporalcentroids/centroids-iteration0-noOfClusters2/part-r-00000
```

I'm adding the file in before starting my job using

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(URI.create(args[2]), job.getConfiguration());
```

And I'm trying to read from the file from setup metod in my mapper using

```
DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf);
```

As I said, I can confirm that the file is on the local system, but the exception is thrown.

I'm running the job in pseudo-distributed mode, on one computer.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can u post how you are reading the file?

If you are using the default file system, and the default is configured to be HDFS, propably it is the error. If you are trying to read the file from local file system you must use:

```
FileSystem.getLocal(context.getConfiguration())
```